# Access token scopes only include openid when authenticating users with Amazon Cognito via ALB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-application-load-balancer

I am authenticating users using Amazon Cognito via an ALB to EKS containers. From the app, I can get the headers set by the ALB: X-Amzn-Oidc-* headers, including the access token and the oidc-data headers. The header part of the X-Amzn-Oidc-Accesstoken should include the list of scopes specified in the user pool app-client. However, the scope value is set to 'openid' only, although on the app client config, I have added: phonenumber, email, ... and openid.

Why are the rest of the scopes not being set?